# Access query amazing

Tags: ms-access

When I do that on access, `SELECT RMonturesImp.N°Fac
FROM RMonturesImp, Rpartielun
WHERE NOT (RMonturesImp.N°Fac IN (1,2,5))
GROUP BY RMonturesImp.N°Fac;`

but when I do this

```
SELECT RMonturesImp.N°Fac
FROM RMonturesImp, Rpartielun
WHERE NOT (RMonturesImp.N°Fac IN Requête2)
GROUP BY RMonturesImp.N°Fac;
```

it doesn't work (it shows 1,2,5 indeed) although the result of Requête2 (which is a query) is also (1,2,5). I can't understand this!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure you understood well-or maybe it's the opposite.
When I put (1,2,5) it's OK and Access shows only the N°Fac different from 1,2 &5. However, when I put Requête2 whose result is basically the same (1,2,5), Access shows all N°Fac (including 1,2,5). @Gustav, could you join a piece of code to explain more clearly?

Comment: Any code that can create an SQL string can be used. Nothing special. The result has to look as your first (working) example. No variation over the second will work. It's that simple.

Comment: The problem is that my working example was just a test because the number (1,2,5) are supposed to be "found automatically" by the query, if you see what I mean. So, I can't let IN(1,2,5) but I need to use "Requête2" :-(

Comment: Yes, so what you need to is to modify the SQL to contain the content of this Requête2 variable.

Comment: Requête2 is a query whose result is exactly (1,2,5). But I think I have an idea of what I will do (I will match 2queries working, and code the stuff on Java, where I "transfered" the database for the graphical interface. Thanks anyway

Comment: Sorry, missed that it is a query. Then you should be able to use a simple Select. See edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite easy. The `IN (1,2,5))` must be explicit as SQL will not evaluate an expression not to say a function to obtain the values for IN.

So build your SQL in code creating the string, or pull the values from a (temp) table.

Try this:

```
SELECT RMonturesImp.N°Fac
FROM RMonturesImp, Rpartielun
WHERE RMonturesImp.N°Fac NOT IN (Select N°Fac From Requête2)
GROUP BY RMonturesImp.N°Fac;
```